# Describing progress of a project

Tags: business-japanese

I would like to know some natural phrases for describing that a project is running along smoothly. This is what I can think of but there may be better expressions.

> 最近のプロジェクトは着々と進んでいます。
>
> 最近のプロジェクトはとても進歩しています。
>
> 最近のプロジェクトはうまく行っています。

Also, I'm looking for phrases that express there was a great deal of progress today.

> 今日はプロジェクトがだいぶ進みましたよ。
>
> 今日はプロジェクトがとても進歩しましたよ。

Any help on phrases, verbs, or adjectives (to express "progressed significantly") would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Just took a look on the thesaurus [here](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E9%A0%86%E8%AA%BF) or [here](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E9%A0%86%E8%AA%BF%E3%81%AB%E9%80%B2%E3%82%80) for some ideas.

順調｛じゅんちょう｝です。 It's going well.

イメージ通{どお}り進｛すす｝んでいます。 It's going as planned

今日｛きょう｝は調子｛ちょうし｝が良｛よ｝さそうです。 Today's pace is looking good.

作業｛さぎょう｝が捗｛はかど｝っています。 Tasks are making progress.

Comment: Thanks! Two questions - Would it be OK to use "~調子がいいです” without the "~そう" or is this too direct? Also, could 作業 refer to a single task, including things like software development?

Comment: @Locksleyu I think 調子がいいです is totally fine :). As for 作業, I'm not sure... I always thing of it as "things to do" or "tasks" but have never counted them as single things.

Comment: @Locksleyu Scratch that, you can count 作業s as in 「一つの作業」etc

Comment: Hmm, so tasks can make progress? Like, not the people that are working on them but the tasks themselves?

Comment: @kuchitsu I think it's one of those hidden subjects, I don't know the proper grammar term, but a google search for 作業が捗る shows results :).

Answer (score 1):

着々と進んでいます and うまく行っています sound good to me.
You'd usually use 進展/進行 rather than 進歩 for a project (プロジェクト/計画/事業/仕事/学習/課題?). For "The project is going smoothly," I would probably say like:

> 「｛[目下]{もっか}/現在｝、プロジェクトは｛着々と/順調に/計画通り｝進んでいます。」
>   「｛目下/現在｝、プロジェクトは｛着々と/順調に/計画通り｝｛進行中です/進行しています｝。」
>   「プロジェクトはうまく行っています。」

---

「今日はプロジェクトがだいぶ進みましたよ。」 sounds good to me. Here I would use 進展 or 前進 instead of 進歩. So, for "There was a great deal of progress today" I think you could say like:

> 「今日はプロジェクトが｛だいぶ/かなり/ずいぶん｝進みましたよ。」
>   「今日はプロジェクトが｛大きく/著しく/だいぶ/かなり/ずいぶん｝｛進展/前進｝しましたよ。」
>   「今日はプロジェクトに｛大きな/著しい｝｛進展/前進｝が｛ありました/見られました｝よ。」